# Search through HTML table columns

Tags: javascript, html

I am developing a site that contains a live search. This live search is used to search for contacts in a contact list (An HTML table). The contact list is a table with 2 columns, with each column containing a contact. The search works but, it returns the whole row, not just the matching columns.

Meaning that if I search for A in a table like the one in the snippet below; the search returns the whole row ( A || B ), not just A. Is there any way I could refine my function to search through columns instead of rows?

Hope I explained myself clearly.

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>B</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>C</td>
    <td>D</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Function

```
<script>    
            function myFunction() {
              //variables 
              var input, filter, table, tr, td, i;
              input = document.getElementById("search");
              filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
              table = document.getElementById("table");
              tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

              for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
                td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
                    if (td) 
                        {
                        if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                            tr[i].style.display = "";
                            } else {
                            tr[i].style.display = "none";
                            }
                        } 
                    }
                }
        </script>
```

Comment: You are setting `display` to `none` or `''` for the whole row `tr[i].style.display = "none";`

Comment: Also your sample is missing the search input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've modified your code to iterate all the `td` elements in your table. instead of hiding the cells that don't contain the filter text I've opted to apply an opacity to them. It makes it clearer in the example what is happening.

When doing work on key down, don't forget to debounce the event. See this post for a good introduction: https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function

```js
function myFunction() {
  //variables 
  var
    input = document.getElementById("search"),
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase(),
    table = document.querySelector('table'),
    cells = table.querySelectorAll('td');

  for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
    var cell = cells[i];
    if (cell.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
      cell.classList.remove('no-match');
    } else {
      cell.classList.add('no-match');
    }
  }
}

const
  form = document.getElementById('form'),
  input = document.getElementById("search");
  
form.addEventListener('submit', onFormSubmit);
input.addEventListener('keyup', onKeyUp);

function onFormSubmit(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  myFunction();
}

function onKeyUp(event) {
  // Debounce this event in your code or you will run into performance issues.
  myFunction();
}
```

```css
.no-match {
 opacity: .2;
}
```

```html
<form id="form">
  <label>
    Filter text
    <input type="text" id="search"/>
  </label>
  <button>Filter</button>
</form>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>B</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>C</td>
    <td>D</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I have altered the function a bit so that it works with onKeyUp, I removed the filter in the brackets, and included it as document.getElementById etc.. to get the data from the search itself. Now a blank page ( No results) is being displayed

Comment: I've updated the answer with a search input, the table now gets filtered on the input the user provides. When the table is empty it probably means none of the cells contain the filter text (according to your code). If I were you, I would not hide the cells but place the text inside a `span` or something and hide those elements.

Comment: Takes mate :) I will try to alter this example for the function to work onkeyup, so it mimics the google live search

Comment: Don't forget to debounce your live search or you will run into performance issues.

Comment: Why does the function work as the example given, but not onkeyup ? I have edited only the last bits ( from Const onwards ) as I think that onkeyup will take care of those bits

Comment: I've updated the answer with a keyup handler. My guess is you kept the `preventDefault()`. In case of a form submit it is needed but preventing the keydown default behaviour means the char never gets added to the input.

Comment: Added a link to the answer with some info on debouncing the event.